# Is there a list like operator in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm now implement such a task:I need to convert PHP variables to javascript

```
$arr['name1'] = 'value1';
$arr['name2'] = 'value2';
```

so that after processing,should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name1 = 'value1';
var name2 = 'value2';
...
```

I hoped to do it this way:

```
<script>
list(<?php echo join(',',array_keys($arr)?>) = <?php echo json_encode(array_values($arr));?>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005960/searching-equivalent-function-way-to-list-from-php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954426/javascript-equivalent-of-phps-list are similar. The first provides a link to and article on http://solutoire.com that provides a way to do this. There isn't a specific JS operator/syntax/function that does that, but there are many ways to accomplish this in JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably misunderstood the question, but wouldn't this work?

```
echo "<script>";
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) 
{
    echo "var $k = $v;";
}
echo "</script>";
```

Comment: Yes,that's almost what I mean.But I'm just not sure if there is a more concise solution like `list`?

Comment: Not built into Javascript. You'd have to use a custom function for that, which would be pretty silly when you can just use an extremely simple loop - not to mention that the loop would be far more readable to other developers.

Comment: If I'm not counting wrongly,you've mentioned silly 2times.You can go away!I don't need your help at all!

Comment: @unknown But it is silly. Just like with your last question, you are creating problems where there are none. Just write the variables in JSON or use `foreach`. What is so much more concise about `list`?

Answer (score 3):

**Check [php.js](http://phpjs.org/)**, they have ported a lot of features of PHP to JS, [list() is listed as experimental](http://github.com/kvz/phpjs/blob/master/_experimental/array/list.js).

Comment: List is more of a language construct; PHP JS doesn't seem to have implemented it, from what I can find.

Comment: @Matchu: I know it's a language construct, I didn't say otherwise. I've provided a link to the php.js experimental port of `list()`.

Comment: Oh, wow. Was that there before? I totally missed it. Give the post a token edit and I'll switch to upvote :)

Comment: @Matchu: Just did, if you upvote me I won't win any rep points as I'm already capped for today - but it can reflect the possible usefulness of the answer. =)

Comment: @AlixAxel, second link in the post is dead.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry.

You might instead consider simply using `json_encode` to print the object to the script.

```
<?php
    $a = array('foo' => 'bar');
    json_encode($a); // returns {"foo":"bar"} which is valid Javascript syntax
?>

<script>var obj = <?php echo json_encode($a); ?></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use json.

```
var arr = { "name1" : "value1", "name2": "value2"}
```

Then to get a value you just access it like a field

```
var firstVal = arr.name1
```

Comment: I need a variable called `name1`,and its value should be `value1`.Not `firstval`

Comment: Just get creative, silly. If you want the variable to be named something else, change the name.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to have a look at [PHP JS](http://phpjs.org/functions/index), it will help  you in your conversion tasks. Thanks

Comment: List is more of a language construct; PHP JS doesn't seem to have implemented it, from what I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it's only possible by help of the controversial 'eval()' function...

```
function list(v,a){
  v=v.split(',');
  for(var s='',i=0;i<v.length;i++)
    s+=v[i]+'='+i+'<'+a+'.length?'+a+'['+i+']:null;';
  return s;
}
```

Usage:

```
eval(list(var_names_as_comma_separated_str, str_name_of_array));
```

Example:

```
A=['one',1,'z1'];
eval(list('x,y,z','A'));
console.log('+-> First: ',x,y,z);  //output: one 1 z1
(function(){
  var z,B=['two',2,'local'];  //note that z is local variable
  console.log('Local.Before: ',x,y,z);  //output: one 1 undefined
  eval(list('x,y,z','B'));
  console.log('Local.After: ',x,y,z);  //output: two 2 local
})()
console.log('+-> Back: ',x,y,z);  //output: two 2 z1 (global z is unchanged)
```

Note: window['var_name'] can't be used to access local variable (variable inside function), so we have no choice other than eval()...